# How to move the textblock location programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textblock

In my WP8, i wanted to move a textblock location from existing place to new place (x,y).
I tried using

```
Canvas.SetTop(text1, y);
Canvas.SetLeft(text1, x);
```

but it fails to change the textblock location. Is there any bestway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move the textbox inside a given grid/canvas u can set the margin programmatically.

```
 textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
```

just adjust the values based on where/how you want to move it

Answer (score 5):

In order to use Canvas.SetLeft and SetTop the textbox needs be a child of a Canvas control. These methods don't work if the control is in a different control.

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
text1.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform {
    X = 10,
    Y = 20
}
```

In this case the control does not need to be inside a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`UpdateLayout()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on the `Canvas` element.